# How does DHCP work when it's not "between" your modem and devices?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I've been looking into different options for running some services on a home server. One such option is [Amahi](http://www.amahi.org). During the setup process they recommend shutting off any other DHCP server on your network so that Amahi can take over as DHCP and DNS for you.

My network is set up starting at the cable modem from my ISP, to my Airport Extreme's WAN port, then to my computers/server over Wi-Fi, and from a LAN port to my switch.

In this setup my Airport acts as the hardware that receives the IP from my ISP. I've also run it in bridge mode in the past while at school so that the school's routers could give my computers an IP directly.

If I switch my Airport to bridge mode, and tell Amahi to be my DHCP, what prevents my computers from getting their IPs from the modem? What mechanism places the Amahi server where the Airport normally is?

Comment: first DO NOT run your router in bridge mode. that is the simplest way to prevent them asking for ISP addresses. to further ensure this, make sure your router does not allow UDP/67 or 68 traffic. Your Amahi documentation is talking about DHCP for clients of your local network only. your router's WAN comes from the ISP dhcp servers, but your internal network hosts should get theirs from Amahi. Hope that helps.

Comment: @FrankThomas Putting the Airport in bridge mode is the only way to stop it from handing out IPs to clients on the LAN.

Comment: that's very unfortunate. I've never ever seen a router you could not turn off DHCP on. can you control the DHCP pool? perhaps limit it to one or no addresses?

Comment: I could limit the range of IPs to one different than the Amahi server would use, but this doesn't answer my question as to how a server that is not between my clients and ISP can act as a DHCP server.

Comment: DHCP works by sending LAN broadcasts, so the server does not need to be between the clients and the ISP. the amahi server could be on the lan next to the other clients, and the clients will get an address from it without issue. The trick is to get only one of the two DHCP servers to respond to the broadcast request for an address. If you limit your airports DHCP pool to give it zero addresses, or just one address that also happens to be the airports address, then your hosts should be able to get their DHCP request answered by teh Amahi server instead of the airport, without bridge mode.